# Active Record Nested Attributes other than :id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm using nested attributes on a form and the nested records are always referred by their `:id`. I use `friendly_id` to avoid showing incremental ids in my application and I plan to do the same on the forms.

However, by checking [ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) documentation I couldn't find any way to use any other than the `:id` to refer to associated records. Is there any way I can use `friendly_id` or specify any other field than `:id`?

I would like to do something like this

```
params = { member: { avatar_attributes: { token: 's0kdmasdods', icon: 'sad' } } }
```

Instead of

```
params = { member: { avatar_attributes: { id: '2', icon: 'sad' } } }
```

Comment: Please, make it clear. Why can't you do what you want? Show the place where you have a problem.

Comment: have you tried overriding the primary key from `id` to `friendly_id`

Comment: @chumakoff If I try to use `token` instead of `id` it won't find the record when saving.

Comment: @BigRon How? `friendly_id` is not a column name, it is a popular gem. If I try to pass a `token` as id it wil give error: can't find a record with that id when saving the parent record.